# C Development Utilities Library

Tags: c, library

I have been working on a small library of development utilities for some time now, incrementally improving and expanding it as I make use of it in other projects. I feel that it is fairly mature now; I've worked out enough bugs that I can say it is decently stable and I feel that it is time for a code review on what I've created so far to make sure everything is kosher.

It has an implementation of better strings and string buffers, a unit testing framework, atomic code profiling framework, cleaner assert-or-fail style checks with a customizable error logging system, and safer memory management utilities.

In any case, here's the repository: https://github.com/daltonwoodard/cdevkit

I'll also post the API's for several of the sections. There are demos of the unit testing framework and code profiling framework in the cdevkit/demos/ directory.

API:

## safemem.h

```
#ifndef __safemem_h_
#define __safemem_h_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include "check.h"
#include "cdk_stack.h"

//
// Memory allocation stats
//
#ifdef TRACK_MEM
    static unsigned long int __sm_bytes_allocated_c = 0; // current
    static unsigned long int __sm_bytes_allocated_t = 0; // total
    static unsigned long int __sm_bytes_allocated_p = 0; // peak

    #define get_bytes_allocated_current() __sm_bytes_allocated_c
    #define get_bytes_allocated_total() __sm_bytes_allocated_t
    #define get_bytes_allocated_peak() __sm_bytes_allocated_p

    #define mem_stats_add( bytes ) __sm_bytes_allocated_c += (bytes);                                       \
        __sm_bytes_allocated_t += (bytes);                                                                  \
        __sm_bytes_allocated_c > __sm_bytes_allocated_p ? __sm_bytes_allocated_p = __sm_bytes_allocated_c   \
                                                        : __sm_bytes_allocated_p += 0;

    #define mem_stats_sub( bytes ) __sm_bytes_allocated_c -= (bytes);
#endif

//
// Pushes a new pointer to the register stack and returns the pointer.
// Note that this function will be called automatically when the register
// system is being used correctly.
// @param  __pr [The current register stack.]
// @param  ptr  [Pointer to the pointer to be registered.]
// @param  ci   [Function call info, automatically provided by macro incokation.]
// @return      [The poitner being registered.]
//
void * __sm_pr_register(cdk_stack * const __pr, void ** ptr,
                        cdk_call_info const * const ci);


//
// Releases the memory from all pointers registered on the stack.
// @param __pr [The current register stack.]
//
void __sm_pr_release_all(cdk_stack * __pr);


//
// Usage macros for the safemem register.
// 
#define sm_using_register() cdk_stack * const __pr = cdk_stack_create()
#define sm_end_register() do { cdk_stack_release( (cdk_stack **)&(__pr) ); } while (0);
#define sm_register(P) __sm_pr_register(__pr, &(void *){ (P) }, call_info())
#define sm_release() cdk_stack_release_with_contents( (cdk_stack **)&(__pr) )


//
// Returns the number of bytes allocated to a given pointer.
//
// Wraps the malloc_size() method from <malloc/malloc.h>
//
size_t __mem_size(void const * const ptr, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define mem_size(P) __mem_size((P), call_info())


//
// Allocates (count * size) bytes of memory.
//
// Note allocate_mem_() is not meant to be called directly. Rather,
// use the allocate_mem() macro.
//
// Returns a (void *) pointer to the head of the allocated block on success,
// or NULL on failure, logging an error report to stderr.
//
void * __allocate_mem(size_t const count, size_t const size,
                      cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define allocate_mem(COUNT, SIZE) __allocate_mem((COUNT), (SIZE), call_info())

#define rallocate_mem(COUNT, SIZE) __sm_pr_register(__pr, \
    &(void *){ __allocate_mem((COUNT), (SIZE), call_info()) }, call_info())


//
// Allocates (size) bytes of memory for (count) objects and
// initializes the allocated region to values of 0.
//
// Note calloc_mem_() is not meant to be called directly. Rather,
// use the calloc_mem() macro.
//
// Returns a (void *) pointer to the head of the allocated block on success,
// or NULL on failure, logging an error report to stderr.
//
void * __calloc_mem(size_t const count, size_t const size,
                    cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define calloc_mem(COUNT, SIZE) __calloc_mem((COUNT), (SIZE), call_info())

#define rcalloc_mem(COUNT, SIZE) __sm_pr_register(__pr, \
    &(void *){ __calloc_mem((COUNT), (SIZE), call_info()) }, call_info())


//
// Attempts to reallocate (size) bytes of memory pointed to by (void * from).
// Note realloc_mem_() is not meant to be called directly. Rather,
// use the realloc_mem() macro.
//
// Returns a (void *) pointer to the head of the reallocated block on success,
// or NULL on failure, logging an error report to stderr.
//
// If the reallocation fails, the memory pointed to by (void * ptr) is free'd.
//
void * __realloc_mem(void * ptr, size_t const size,
                     cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define realloc_mem(FROM, SIZE) __realloc_mem((FROM), (SIZE), call_info())

#define rrealloc_mem(FROM, SIZE) __sm_pr_register(__pr, \
    &(void *){ __realloc_mem((FROM), (SIZE), call_info()) }, call_info())


//
// Allocates (size) bytes of memory on a page boundary.
//
// Note valloc_mem_() is not meant to be called directly. Rather,
// use the valloc_mem() macro.
//
// Returns a (void *) pointer to the head of the allocated block on success,
// or NULL on failure, logging an error report to stderr.
//
void * __valloc_mem(size_t const size, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define valloc_mem(SIZE) __valloc_mem((SIZE), call_info())

#define rvalloc_mem(SIZE) __sm_pr_register(__pr,               \
    &(void *){__valloc_mem((SIZE), call_info()) }, call_info())


//
// Copies (size) bytes of memory counted from the head of the source (from) 
// to the destination (to).
// 
// Returns a (void *) pointer to the head of the copied block,
// i.e. the original (to).
//
void * __cpy_mem(void * to, void const * const from, 
        size_t const size, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define cpy_mem(T, F, S) __cpy_mem( (T), (F), (S), call_info() )


//
// Returns a (deep) copy of the given memory; i.e. a non-aliased clone.
//
void * __cpy_of(void const * const ptr, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define cpy_of(P) __cpy_of((P), call_info())

#define rcpy_of(P) __sm_pr_register(__pr,                          \
    &(void *){ __cpy_of((P), call_info()) }, call_info())


//
// Returns a (deep) copy of the given memory up to the given length;
// i.e. a non-aliased clone.
//
void * __cpyn_of(void const * const ptr, size_t const len,
                 cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define cpyn_of(P, N) __cpyn_of((P), (N), call_info() )

#define rcpyn_of(P, N) __sm_pr_register(__pr,                          \
    &(void *){ __cpyn_of((P), (N), call_info()) }, call_info())


//
// Clears all memory allocated to the given pointer,
// setting all bytes to value '\0'.
//
void __clear_mem(void * const ptr, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define clear_mem(P) __clear_mem((P), call_info())


//
// Sets all memory allocated to the given pointer, 
// setting all bytes to the given value.
//
void __set_mem(void * const ptr, char const val,
               cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define set_mem(P, V) __set_mem((P), (V), call_info())


//
// Checks whether the given pointer is NULL valued; 
// i.e. an invalid (or dangling) pointer.
//
// Note, __verify_pointer() is not meant to be called directly. 
// Rather, use the verify_pointer() macro.
//
// Returns 0 if the pointer is valid, -1 if it is invalid.
//
bool __verify_pointer(void const ** const ptr,
                      cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define verify_pointer(PTR) __verify_pointer( &(void *){ (PTR) }, call_info() )


//
// Free's the memory allocated to the given pointer.
//
// Note, __free_mem() is not meant to be called directly. 
// Rather, use the free_mem() macro.
//
// Upon success, the return value is void. If the pointer passed was NULL 
// valued, then a warning is logged to stderr.
//
void __free_mem(void ** ptr, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define free_mem(PTR) __free_mem( &(void *){ (PTR) }, call_info() )


//
// Calls the dedicated object (or data structure, or struct) desctructor 
// and then free's memory allocated to the object (or data strucutre, 
// or struct) itself.
//
// Note, __free_obj() is not meant to be called directly. 
// Rather, use the free_obj() macro.
//
// Upon success, the return value is void. If the pointer passed was
// NULL valued, then a warning is logged to stderr. The caller's destructor 
// function is expected to return void, and errors within it's own scope are 
// not expected to be propogated upwards to free_obj_().
// 
// Note also that the caller's destructor method IS NOT expected to 
// deallocate the object itself; rather, only the memory allocated to 
// any of it's contents. If, however, this behavior cannot be avoided
// the given pointer MUST be set to NULL, otherwise free_obj_() will fail 
// on attempt to deallocate. To allow for this, the destructor is passed a
// (void **) pointer that can be dereferenced to set the pointer itself 
// to NULL.
//
void __free_obj(void ** ptr, void (* destructor)(void **),
                cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define free_obj(OBJ, DST) __free_obj(&(void *){ (OBJ) }, (DST), call_info())

#endif
```

## cstring.h

```
#ifndef __cstring_h_
#define __cstring_h_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "safemem.h"
#include "check.h"


// The standard cstring is an immutable
// NULL-terminated char const array with
// length information included.
typedef struct {
    size_t const len;
    char const * const str_val;
} cstring;

// The cstringbuffer is a mutable
// and resizeable NULL-terminated char array.
typedef struct {
    size_t len;
    size_t capacity;
    char * str_val;
} cstringbuffer;


#define as_string( s ) (s)->str_val
#define cstring_len( s ) (s)->len;


//
// Returns a new cstring with the given literal value.
// Note that __create_cstring() should not be called direcly. Rather,
// the new_cstring() macro should be used.
// If sufficient memory cannot be allocaed, the return value is NULL.
//
cstring * __create_cstring(char const * const str_val);

#define new_cstring( s ) __create_cstring( (s) )


//
// Returns a new cstring with the result of the formatted input.
// Note that __create_cstring() should not be called direcly. Rather,
// the new_cstring() macro should be used.
// If sufficient memory cannot be allocaed, the return value is NULL.
//
cstring * __fcreate_cstring(char const * const fmt, ...);

#define new_fcstring( f, ... ) __fcreate_cstring( (f), ##__VA_ARGS__ )


//
// Releases the memory allocated to the given cstring and sets the pointer to NULL.
//
void __cstring_release(cstring ** s, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define cstring_release( s ) __cstring_release( (s), call_info() )


//
// Creates a new cstringbuffer.
//
cstringbuffer * __create_cstringbuffer(size_t const capacity);

#define new_cstringbuffer() __create_cstringbuffer(0) // We let the method use the default capacity by passing in zero
#define new_cstringbuffer_wcap( c ) __create_cstringbuffer( (c) )


//
// Releases the memory allocated to the given cstringbuffer and sets the pointer to NULL.
//
void __cstringbuffer_release(cstringbuffer ** b, cdk_call_info const * const ci);

#define cstringbuffer_release( b ) __cstringbuffer_release( (b), call_info() )


//
// Ensures that the given cstringbuffer has the given capacity.
// Returns 1 on success, or 0 on failure. If the memory cannot be
// allocated, the contents of the original cstringbuffer are left
// unchanged.
//
int cstringbuffer_ensure_capacity(cstringbuffer * const b, size_t const capacity);


//
// Returns a copy of the given cstring as a cstringbuffer, or
// NULL on failure. In either case, the contents of the
// original cstring are left unchanged.
//
cstringbuffer * cstring_to_buffer(cstring const * const s);


//
// Returns a copy of the given cstringbuffer as a cstring, or
// NULL on failure. In either case, the contents of the original
// cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
//
cstring * cstringbuffer_to_string(cstringbuffer const * const b);


//
// Writes the single given char to the string buffer. Returns,
// 1 on success, or 0 on failure. In the case of failure, the contents
// of the original cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
//
int cstringbuffer_write_char(cstringbuffer * const b, char const c);


//
// Appends a copy of the string value of the given cstring to the given cstringbuffer.
// Returns 1 on success, or 0 on failure. In the case of failure, the contents of the
// original cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
//
int cstringbuffer_append(cstringbuffer * const b, cstring const * const s);


//
// Appends a copy of the string value of the given string pointed to by 'str' to the
// given cstringbuffer. Returns 1 on success, or 0 on failure. In the case of failure,
// the contents of the original cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
//
int __cstringbuffer_append_allocated_source(cstringbuffer * const b, char const * const str, size_t const len);

#define cstringbuffer_append_alloced( b, s, l ) __cstringbuffer_append_allocated_source( (b), (s), (l) )


//
// Appends a copy of the string value of the given string literal to the given cstringbuffer.
// Returns 1 on success, or 0 on failure. In the case of failure, the contents of the
// original cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
//
int __cstringbuffer_append_literal(cstringbuffer * const b, char const * const l, size_t const len);

#define cstringbuffer_append_literal( b, l ) __cstringbuffer_append_literal( (b), (l), sizeof((l)) )


//
// Takes a format string and a variadic list of arguments to append to the given cstringbuffer.
// Returns 1 on success, or 0 on failure. In the case of failure, the contents of the
// original cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
//
int __cstringbuffer_append_format(cstringbuffer * const b, char const * const fmt, ...);

#define cstringbuffer_append_format( b, f, ... ) __cstringbuffer_append_format( (b), (f), ##__VA_ARGS__ )


//
// Returns a dedicated copy of the given cstring, or
// NULL if sufficient memory cannot be allocated. In either
// case, the contents of the original cstring are left unchanged.
//
cstring * cstring_clone(cstring const * const s);


//
// Returns a dedicated copy of the given cstringbuffer, or
// NULL if sufficient memory cannot be allocated. In either
// case, the contents of the original cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
// 
cstringbuffer * cstringbuffer_clone(cstringbuffer const * const b); 


//
// Returns a new cstring whose contents consist of the string value of the
// first argument concatenated with that of the second, or NULL on failure.
// In either case, the contents of both arguments are left unchanged.
//
cstring * cstring_concat(cstring const * const s, cstring const * const with);


//
// Returns a new cstring constructed from the variadic list of cstrings passed to it,
// or NULL on failure. In either case, the contents of all cstrings passed in are left
// unchanged. Note that if a single cstring is passed in, the behavior is identical to
// that of cstring_clone. Note also that if two cstrings are passed, the behavior is
// identical to that of cstring_concat.
//
cstring * cstring_join(size_t const num, ...);


//
// Returns a copy of the provided cstring's value as a normal char array.
// If sufficient memory cannot be allocated, the return value is NULL. In
// either case, the contents of the cstring are left unchanged.
//
char * cstring_to_char_array(cstring const * const s);


//
// Returns a copy of the provided cstringbuffer's value as a normal char array.
// If sufficient memory cannot be allocated, the return value is NULL. In
// either case, the contents of the cstringbuffer are left unchanged.
// 
char * cstringbuffer_to_char_array(cstringbuffer const * const b); 


//
// Returns a copy of the substring of the given cstring indicated by the given indices.
// If sufficient memory could not be allocated, the return value is NULL. In
// either case, the contents of the cstring are left unchanged.
//
cstring * cstring_substring(cstring const * const s, size_t const from, size_t const to);


//
// Returns the first index from the left of the given char in the given cstring,
// or -1 if not present.
//
int char_indexl(cstring const * const s, char const c);


//
// Returns the first index from the left of the given char in the given cstringbuffer,
// or -1 if not present.
//
int b_char_indexl(cstringbuffer const * const s, char const c);


//
// Returns the first index from the right of the given char in the given cstring,
// or -1 if not present.
//
int char_indexr(cstring const * const s, char const c);


//
// Returns the first index from the right of the given char in the given cstringbuffer,
// or -1 if not present.
//
int b_char_indexr(cstringbuffer const * const s, char const c);


//
// Returns the count of how many times the given char occurs in the given cstring.
//
int count_char_occurrence(cstring const * const s, char const c);


//
// Returns the count of how many times the given char occurs in the given cstringbuffer.
//
int b_count_char_occurrence(cstringbuffer const * const s, char const c);


//
// Returns a copy of the given cstring, with all alphabetic characters converted
// to upper case. If sufficient memory could not be allocated, the return value is NULL.
// In either case, the contents of the cstring are left unchanged.
//
cstring * cstring_toupper(cstring const * const s);


//
// Returns a copy of the given cstring, with all alphabetic characters converted
// to lower case. If sufficient memory could not be allocated, the return value is NULL.
// In either case, the contents of the cstring are left unchanged.
//
cstring * cstring_tolower(cstring const * const s);


//
// Returns the index of the first occurence of the substring in the given cstring, or -1 if not found.
//
int cstrstr(cstring const * const haystack, cstring const * const needle);


//
// Returns the index of the first occurence of the substring in the given cstring, or -1 if not found.
//
int cstrstrl(cstring const * const haystack, char const * const needle);


//
// Returns the index of the first occurence of the substring in the given cstringbuffer, or -1 if not found.
//
int cstrbstr(cstringbuffer const * const haystack, cstring const * const needle);


//
// Returns the index of the first occurence of the substring in the given cstringbuffer, or -1 if not found.
//
int cstrbstrl(cstringbuffer const * const haystack, char const * const needle);


//
// Returns the lexicographic comparison value between the given cstrings.
//
int cstring_cmp(void const * const a, void const * const b);


//
// Returns the lexicographic comparison value between the given cstrings,
// ignoring case; i.e., "hello", "HELLO", and "HeLlO" all compare to 0.
//
int cstring_cmp_ncase(void const * const a, void const * const b);


//
// Returns the lexicographic comparison value between the given cstringbuffers.
//
int cstringbuffer_cmp(void const * const a, void const * const b);


//
// Returns the lexicographic comparison value between the given cstringbuffers,
// ignoring case; i.e., "hello", "HELLO", and "HeLlO" all compare to 0.
//
int cstringbuffer_cmp_ncase(void const * const a, void const * const b);


#endif
```

Unfortunately I can't add anything else due to character limits, but the remainder of the project is in the repo I linked.

Answer (score 4):

## Standards

> Note also that this project is developed to be compliant with the C11 standard.

Cool, let's find non-standard behavior.

The first thing that jumps out to me is your usage of double underscores.

Both C99 and C11 say (in section 7.1.3):

> All identiﬁers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

You include `<malloc/malloc.h>` everywhere. The only operating system where I could find that header file is MacOS. This is definitely not standard.

You seem to be very dependent on the function `malloc_size` in many places. As far as I know, only MacOS implements it.

You use the function `valloc`. This is a non-standard function that has been marked as obsolete in 4.3 BSD in 1986. You can get this functionality from a standard (not C, but at least POSIX) by using the `posix_memalign` function.

## Problematic behavior

In `cstring_cmp` and `cstringbuffer_cmp` you compare with the shortest string with `strncmp` which means that you're only comparing the prefixes of the strings (I think, I haven't dug into the exact details of the library) and why not just use `memcmp` since you're not comparing C strings anyway.

It's possible to write `\0` into a cstringbuffer with `cstringbuffer_write_char` (and other functions) that will update the length to include that and later append further characters at the end of the buffers, but you're then using normal `strcmp`, `strncpy`, etc. to compare and copy the strings which will not do what you want. Either disallow `\0` explicitly or use functions that don't get confused by it.

`allocate_mem` has a good prototype with `count` and `size`. This is just like `calloc` and it's what a modern memory allocator should do. But, you miss the point of why `calloc` does it. The main reason is that you can detect overflows when multiplying `count * size`. You don't check for overflow in that multiplication which can lead to security issues.

## Matters of taste

You're always allocating a struct on the stack, then malloc the same struct, then return a copy. Why? It seems like extra work.

Macros with magic `goto error;` with the `error:` label being outside of the macro are horrifying.

You do `do { ... } while (0)` in macros, this is good style. But you then defeat half the purpose of building macros this way by adding the `;` inside the macro. for example `if (foo) log_error("foo"); else do_something();` will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

I've only looked (briefly) at the `cstring.h` part so far.  I like it for the most part. It looks like it could help projects avoid the chaos and subtle error that often creep into `C` code that uses lots of character arrays.

Suggestions:

- You seem to only use dynamic (heap) memory.   Particularly in embedded code, there are times when using the heap is just a bad idea. What about support for stack-based strings?  If I make a character array of my own, I'd like a way to give you the address and size, and get back a wrapped `cstring` that works with the rest of the API. Let the calling code manage the memory allocation and the library manage the string manipulation.
- `int`s are for counting and math. `int` is a poor way to model "1 on success, or 0 on failure".  You *don't* want the calling code using the return values for counting or math, so you shouldn't choose a return type that encourages it. this context, 0 and 1 are magic numbers. You could use `bool` instead, or define your own enumeration.